# c code serialization of double and floats with a exponent base 10

Tags: c, networking, serialization, floating-point, double

I need a fast solution to serialize float (4 bytes) and double (8 bytes) into binary representation to send them over the network.

The problem is the format I have to use :

> mantissa * 10^exponent

where the mantissa is a signed integer (4 bytes when encoding the float and 8 bytes for the double) and the exponent is coded on 1 byte.

The exponent is a base 10, so bit shifting tricks seem useless to me and I have to separate the mantissa from the exponenet in order to serialize them.

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Convert them to text? Or just send them as they are if you can assume that all parties will use IEEE-754.

Comment: actually, the format used by all parties is not IEEE-754 but as i said mantissa*10^exponent. Converting to text ... well actually i'm trying to find something really fast. under IEEE-754 you can find some pretty nice routines (Kernighan's like) but for base 10 ... actually i'm kind of struggling.

Comment: That's a pretty awful format for speed. All machines I have ever encountered are binary and having to convert to decimal costs. That said, if you are sending them over the network, speed of conversion is not going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: yeah i know, it's not the most efficient. but that's the protocol. there is nothing i can do about it. but still speed of conversion can be a matter, i do have loads of float/double to process. I can't multithread the process, it has to be achieved within one memory context, therefore if the conversion is not optimal i can run into bottlenecks ...

Comment: How could conversion ever be the bottleneck? You said you were sending it over the wire? Surely that's going to swamp the conversion.

Comment: ok, i do maybe need to send one thousand doubles packed into binaries per message. if every packing costs 1 micrsosecond --->total = 1 ms, and actually the transport time between machine A & B is << 1ms ...

Comment: Why can't you just send them in the exact representation that you already have?  What are you trying to gain by transforming the representation?

Comment: @TJD as he said: protocol conformance. What would be the benefit of not converting the data if the receiver doesn't understand the stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement that the encoded mantissa is an integer confuses me.  It has to represent some form of a floating point number, perhaps encoded in four or eight bytes.

For any positive number x, you can uniquely express `x` as

```
x = 10^(f + n) = 10^f * 10^n
```

where `n` is an integer, and `0 <= f < 1`.  Note that

```
f + n = log10(x)
```

by definition.

For positive *x*, the simplest code I can imagine is this:

```
double lg10 = log10(x);
double f = fmod(lg10, 1.0);
int n = lg10 - f
encode_mantissa(pow(10.0, f));
encode_exponent(n);
```

For negative `x`, you need to take the absolute value before applying the above code, and then encode the sign in whatever way is appropriate.

The cost of this is three non-trivial floating point operations, but I these are all done in hardware these days on general-purpose CPUs.  You still have to solve the problem of encoding the mantissa into a four or eight byte value.

Comment: In C99 / POSIX you can use `double n, f = modf(lg10, &n)` to directly break up `lg10` into fractional and integer parts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I wasn't aware of the `modf` function.

Comment: @Dale:  my format is Mantissa*10^exponent, where Mantissa is a signed integer,  think of -3.14 = -314*10^(-2).

Comment: @Dale: since log10 is an integral, then i will have to deal with exponenet approximation...

Comment: @promic: You'll need to decide how many digits of precision you want in your integer mantissa, and then shift `n` and `10^f` appropriately.  Re your other comment, I don't understand what you mean by "log10 is an integral".  The code above gives you an exact integer exponent, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: i guess this is how the machine calculate it : log10(x)=ln(x)/ln(10) .... integral = infinite sum

Comment: @promic: Functions like log10 and friends are not implemented in terms of integration, even if they can be defined that way from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: @Dale: well maybe i'm not clear. it cannot work. exemple : X=2.3,  the perfect representation would be 23x10^-1, or 230x10^-2. if i decide to do your way :lg10 = 0.3617278(...) f = fmod(log10,1.0)=lg10, n= lg10 - lg10 = 0. so i end up with encode_mantissa(pow(10.0,0.36172727....)) which is not ok. because my mantissa will be equal to 10^0.3617... ~ 2.3 and encode_exponent(0).

Comment: Take advantage of the fact that "mant * 10^expt == (mant * 10) * 10^*(expt - 1)".

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to look at the representation?

How about using the htonl and ntohl functions at the respective ends of your connections, and send them in binary.

Comment: hmmmm ... ok, but ntohl is using a long representation of the decimal. which means IEEE 754 representation. it's not what i need.

Comment: What I'm saying is to separate the 'get the number' over the network part of the problem from anything else.  Take your float, convert it to network order, transmit it, convert it to the new (possibly different) host order, and memcpy back the result into a float.  Now you have your original value on the other side of the network connection and if you want it in a decimal representation, that's a different problem.

Comment: hmm ... actually i am not the developper of the server. it is a service provider which has set this protocol. so i'm only playing on the client side